# How to make a web project available through gh-pages?

Tags: angularjs, git, web, hosting, yeoman-generator

I have a simple web project that I made on the top of https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular.

This generates a great project environment with bower and grunt support, where the .js, .html, and .css files are positioned inside a folder called "app" (similar structure to https://github.com/jgatjens/angular-pokemon).

Everything is working great in localhost. I run a command code (grunt serve) and it starts to run into the browser. However, I am not being able to make the same be available online.

It is important to highlight that **I don`t want to** "publish it officially", **I just want to** be able to send a link to my friends, so they could try it (as users would) and give me feedback on it.

I am not talking about sharing the code. I just want to make it available as it would be for users once it is done.

For example, if I go to https://ng-pokemon.firebaseapp.com, I can try what the repository https://github.com/jgatjens/angular-pokemon has.

**How to use gh-pages to make a subfolder project available?**(in this case, "/app")

Any clue about how could I do that?

I am just an enthusiast that don`t have much experience in making web projects available.

Thanks in advance,
Roger.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can create a new private repository on github and then add your friends so they can access it. Then they will checkout the project using something like `git clone <your_repo>`. If you're talking about giving your friends access to the actual webpage, then you need to setup the project on a public accessible machine or setup some kind of port forwarding between your router and your local machine.

Comment: do you want to share the web app that you can access on **your localhost** with your friends?

Comment: Hello all, sorry for my lack of clarity. What I want is to present them the develop the web app on its "production form". For example, I send you the link of the web app and you can interact with the buttons, fill the forms, and use it as a user would do. Let me know if it is clear now and thanks for your support.

Comment: @RogerAlmeidaLeite - Like I said in my comment. You'll need to setup your environment on a public accessible host or setup some kind of port forwarding between your router and you local machine to achieve this.

Comment: @cyclone - any suggestion where I could start looking for that? I could not find any tutorial or example, maybe I am looking for the wrong keywords.

Comment: The easiest way would be to signup for cheap shared hosting solution. Just google for web hosting or something similar - what you'll need is a web hotel where you can deploy your application. You can also try to google for something like <brand of your router> port forwarding or similar to see if and how you can configure your router to forward a port to your local computer. In the later case you'll then give an url like `http://<ip_of_router>` to you friends, the router will then forward any request to port 80 to your local computer.

Comment: [How to access a local website from internet with port forwarding](https://managewp.com/how-to-access-a-local-website-from-internet-with-port-forwarding)

Comment: Does [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) serve your purposes?

Comment: @BaherRamzy I guess not. I did try, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out what I should do in the case of a project that is build in a subfolder structure. Which is a standard in yeoman projects, by the way.

After all, I discovered that **gh-pages do the service**. 
To do so I needed to:

1 - create a subtree for the subfolder where the project is built and push it to the gh-pages branch.

```
git checkout master # you can avoid this line if you are in master...
git subtree split --prefix dist -b gh-pages # create a local gh-pages branch      containing the splitted output folder
git push -f origin gh-pages:gh-pages # force the push of the gh-pages branch to the remote gh-pages branch at origin
git branch -D gh-pages # delete the local gh-pages because you will need it: ref
```

2- after that, the index.html page was already being identified by the http://username.github.io/projectname page link. However, I was still missing the libraries references created automatically by bower. So and simply copy and paste the folder bower_components into the "/app" folder.

3 - I did an update of the branch again and it work sweetly.

ps_1: probably if I have to add a new library I will need to copy it manually from my outside bower_components to my inside bower_components.

ps_2: I also create a grunt task to facilitate further deploys:

```
grunt.task.registerTask('push-pages', function(){
   var shell = require('shelljs');
    shell.exec('git subtree split --prefix docs -b gh-pages');
    shell.exec('git push -f origin gh-pages:gh-pages');
    shell.exec('git branch -D gh-pages')
});
```

So, I just run 'grunt push-pages' and the update on the GitHub page is done.

ps_2.1: to do that "shelljs" is required. In my case, I added it on npm package.json, just to make sure that I will never forget it.

It is not the best solution on earth, but it worked fine =).

font: https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket by Atlassian offers free unlimited private hosting for Git for small teams. I've used them in the past for various private projects.

https://bitbucket.org/

If you want your friends to simply view some code and give feedback, it might be easier to just share a secret gist with them rather than setting up an entire repo.

https://gist.github.com/

Edit: Since you are actually looking to **host** as opposed to sharing your code, you will need to find a hosting solution.

Comment: He also have the option to setup port forwarding on his router if supported. Then he should be able to give his friends the routers ip address which in turn then will forward any requests on port 80 to the local machine.